# How to use array of results of a function call getting “Result of call is unused”

Tags: arrays, swift, function

*Before marking as duplicate: I have researched and found plenty of threads to this topic, but all of them solve it by silencing the warning with _ =. I don't want to silence the warning. I want to use the result!*

I am creating a messaging feature within my app and trying to have the incoming/outgoing messages align to the left/right sides. I have a function called loadPosts() that returns the value 'incoming' which is an array of values.  I'd like to use those results in the setCell function within tableView to complete the format of the messaging page. The app is running but am getting the warning 'Result of loadPosts is unused' and it's not loading all results of the query.  Code is in included below, I'm completely stuck and appreciate any help:

```
var incoming = [String].self

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    loadPosts()
}


// Load Post Function
    func loadPosts()->[String] {
        self.hhmessages = messages
        for i in 0 ..< self.hhmessages.count {
          if me == self.hhmessages[i]["senderusername"]!! as! String {
                                let incoming = 0
                                return
                            }
          if me == self.hhmessages[i]["recipient"]!! as! String {
                                let incoming = 1
                                return


                }

                        return
          }

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    return incoming.init()
}
```

// TableView Code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ConversationCell

    // shortcuts
    cell.messageLbl.text = messagetext
    cell.dateLbl.text = date
    cell.smavaImg.image = image
    cell.postpictureImg.image = smimages

    func setCell(incoming:[Int]) {
        var layoutAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute
        var layoutConstant: CGFloat
        let tempObj = incoming
        if incoming == [1] {
            print(tempObj, "incoming")
            cell.bubbleImageView.image=#imageLiteral(resourceName: "chat_bubble_received")
            cell.messageLbl.textColor = UIColor.black
            layoutAttribute = .left
            layoutConstant = 10
        }else {
            if incoming == [0] {
                print(tempObj, "outgoing")
                cell.bubbleImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chat_bubble_sent")
            }
            cell.messageLbl.textColor = UIColor.white
            layoutAttribute = .right
            layoutConstant = -10
        }
        cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.bubbleImageView, attribute: layoutAttribute, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: layoutAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: layoutConstant))

    }
    setCell(incoming: [Int()])
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Change `loadPosts()` to `let arr = loadPosts()`. Done.

Comment: Umm... so just assign the function's return value to something? `let someVariable = loadPosts()`. Then do something with `someVariable`. Or create a property on the object and assign the return value to that.

Comment: Your code is a jumbled mess. Your `loadPosts()` function won't compile, since it has 3 different `return` statements that don't return a value. I'm not sure what the line `var incoming = [String].self` will do. I'm also not sure what the line `return incoming.init()` will do.

Comment: Ok, apparently `[String].self` evaluates to `Array<String>.Type`. Thus `incoming.init()` creates a new, empty String array. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Thanks for responding.  I tried that but am still getting the message that results are unused.

Comment: @DuncanC, thank you for your feedback.  I'm new to Swift so I'm learning as I go.  The two statements you called out were error correction suggestions via Xcode

Comment: @techgirl What is `incoming` supposed to actually represent?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka, incoming is used to determine if it's an incoming or outgoing message based on the sender.  If incoming is one the table cells will align right, if 0 they'll align left.

Comment: @techgirl Is the value for `incoming` supposed to be what is returned by the `loadPosts()` method?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka, yes it's supposed to be returned from loadPosts and used by setCell.

Answer (score 1):

Since you intend to store the result of `loadPosts()` into `incoming` to be used later, just do that. Type the `incoming` property as an array, like so:

```
var incoming: [Int] = []
```

This indicates that `incoming` should have the type `[Int]` (i.e. an array of `Int`s), and should be initialized to an empty array (since we will not have its contents ready yet at the time of the object's creation).

Then, when you call `loadPosts()`, just assign the result to the `incoming` property:

```
self.incoming = self.loadPosts()
```

Then you can refer to `self.incoming` later on.

Note that this is assuming `incoming` is an array of `Int`s, using `0` for left, and `1` for right. While this will technically work, I'd recommend using an enum instead, for greater clarity:

```
enum Direction {
    case left
    case right
}
```

Then you can type the property as:

```
var incoming: [Direction] = []
```

And you can add things to the array like so:

```
self.incoming.append(.left) // or .right
```

You'll want to change the return type of `loadPosts()` to return `[Direction]` as well.

Note that even after doing this, your code still will require quite a bit of cleanup before it compiles properly. I recommend reading through the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309), which will help you get a stronger grasp of the language and subsequently help you to write working code.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question.  I've applied your suggested changes and I think I'm still messing up somewhere.  Incoming still isn't being formatted to the left/right. It appears it's not reaching that if statement inside of setCell.

Comment: I realized that setCell is receiving the first value for incoming but it's not looping through the remaining values in the array.  It's counting the number of values however.